# $\lVert f \rVert_{\Phi} < \infty$ for every $f$ measurable and satisfying a certain condition

Tags: proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

Let $\Phi : [0, \infty) \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ a convex, strictly incrasing function, with $\Phi(0)=0$.

Let $L^{\Phi}(0,1)=\{f:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R} \text{ measurable}:\int_0^1\Phi\left( \frac{|f(t)|}{\lambda} \right) \, dt< \infty \text{ for some } \lambda>0\}$

Let $\lVert f \rVert_{\Phi} = \inf \{\lambda > 0 : \int_0^1\Phi\left( \frac{|f(t)|}{\lambda} \right)\, dt < 1\}$

Show that $\lVert f \rVert_{\Phi}<\infty, \forall f \in L^{\Phi}(0,1)$.

My try: $f$ must have finite integral, for if it is not the case, since $\Phi$ must be eventually always be larger than $1$ for every $x>M$ for some $M$ (easy to prove), then we have

$$\int_0^1\Phi\left( \frac{|f(t)|}{\lambda} \right) \, dt \geq \int_{E_1}\frac{|f(t)|}{\lambda} = \infty, \forall \lambda>0$$
where 
$$E_1=\{x\in(0,1):|f(x)|\geq \lambda M\}$$ so $f$ wouldn't belong to $L^{\Phi}(0,1)$ in the first place.
On the other hand, is $f$ is integrable, then, letting $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$, the argument of $\Phi$ tends to zero, and $\Phi$ must be close to $0$ as its argument approaches $0$. Therefore the whole integral tends to zero.

More specifically, we can suppose $\exists \, \delta: \Phi(x)<\epsilon\  \forall x<\delta $, and that $\frac{|f(x)|}{\lambda} < \delta$ everywhere for $\lambda$ large enough, and so

$$\int_0^1\Phi\left( \frac{|f(t)|}{\lambda} \right) \, dt \leq \int_0^1 \delta\, dt$$
for $\lambda$ large enough.

Is it correct? My doubt is, mainly, that it feels awkward to bound those integrals like that without assuming continuity on $\Phi$ or some stronger condition that is usually assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim that $|f (x)|/\lambda <\delta $ everywhere is not correct. However your general idea is correct. To conclude, by the monotone convergence theorem, it suffices that pointwise the function converges to zero, and it does so monotonously.

Comment: Btw. a finitevalued convex function is continuous everywhere, in particular it is continuous at zero which is needed for pointwise convergence to 0 as lambda goes to infinity

Comment: That is perfectly clear, thank you. Is the first part correct?

Comment: It is,  but you don't need to show integrability of f. Integrability of $\Phi (f/\lambda) $ for some lambda suffices.  You will see this when you prove rigorously what I sketched (you may also use the dominated convergence theorem instead of monotone convergence. This isaubemajamg less elegant but much easier)

Comment: Yup, I need to use that fact when I apply the theorem. If I recall correctly, one must suppose $\Phi\left(\frac{|f|}{n}\right)$ is finite for at least some $n$ in order to conclude. Thank you

Comment: To apply dominated convergence theorem you need to show that the integral over it is finite, not the function itself. To apply monotone convergence theorem you normally would need monotonuously increasing convergence and you need some integrability too to turn this around

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant, the integral sign got lost in the keyboard.